# How can I add fields to the default order Item list view?

Tags: lightning, related-list, list-view, customization, orderitem

If I click the ***"hyperlinked related list title with count"*** on the Order Items related list on my Order page / layout,

Then it navigates to a default list of Order Items.

**How can I add/remove fields for this list?**

I have tried creating and assigning a new compact layout as I've seen suggested elsewhere but this does not work. Search layouts are not available for Order Item...

[image: The list I want to add fields to]

For more context,

**Where I'm navigating from:**

[image: Where I'm navigating from]

**An Aside:**

If I examine the http call from the refreshing the listview in question, in the JSON payload I can see:

```
"listViewIdOrName":"OrderItems"
```

Comment: Because there are a lot of "special cases" around Order and Opportunity products and I had been concerned that I was running into one of those but thankfully it turned out to be ignorance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by editing the fields that were specified on the related list configuration, on the parent / Order layout.

Turns out that this was easily solved. I expect that this behaviour follows throughout Salesforce. I.e. when you click the link on a related list on a page layout, that the full list which is displayed then has the same fields as were applied on the "source layout"

This is what happens when developers try to admin!